# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'fnFilterClear'

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am getting this error in the console :

```
 "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'fnFilterClear'"
```

My code :

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var selectedColumn = $('#columnlist').find(":selected").text();

$('#csearchtext').bind("change paste keyup", function () {
    var input = $('#csearchtext').val();
    var dropdownindex = $("select[name='columnlist'] option:selected").index();

    console.log(dropdownindex);

    $('#table_id').dataTable().fnFilter(input, dropdownindex + 1, false, true, true, false);
});

$('#columnlist').on('change', function () {

    $('#table_id').dataTable().fnFilterClear();

});

$('#dblist').on('change', function () {

    var selected = $('#dblist').find(":selected").text();
    tablefill(selected);

});

$('#search').click(function () {

    var selected = $('#dblist').find(":selected").text();
    tablefill(selected);

});

function tablefill(selected) {
    $('.advsearchbar').show();
    $('#stable').show();

    $('#table_id').dataTable({
        "sAjaxSource": '/php/connect/searchtablequery.php',
        "bProcessing": true,
        "sScrollY": "500px",
        "bDeferRender": true,
        "bDestroy": true,
        "sAjaxDataProp": "",
        "fnServerParams": function (aoData) {
            aoData.push({ "name": "db", "value": selected });
        },
        "aoColumns": [
            { "mData": "calldate" },
            { "mData": "recordingfile" },
            { "mData": "uniqueid" },
            { "mData": "src" },
            { "mData": "did" },
            { "mData": "lastapp" },
            { "mData": "dst" },
            { "mData": "disposition" },
            { "mData": "duration" },
            { "mData": "userfield" },
            { "mData": "accountcode"}],
        "iDisplayLength": 20,
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "sDom": '<"H"Tfr>t<"F"ip>',
        "oTableTools": {
            "sSwfPath": "/DataTables/extras/TableTools/media/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
            "aButtons": [
                "copy", "csv", "xls", "pdf",
                {
                    "sExtends": "collection",
                    "sButtonText": "Save",
                    "aButtons": ["csv", "xls", "pdf"]
                }]
        }
    });
 }
});
```

The javascript is firing just fine but the one spot that triggers the `fnfilterclear` has that error prompted.

Comment: Okay...probably the dataTable() function is not returning what you expect. Start debugging there.

Comment: Do you have the appropriate js file included? That function is a plugin for datatables, not part of the main API.

Comment: So what would be the js file I need to include ? Would it be the tabletools ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at http://datatables.net/plug-ins/api#how_to How to use Datatable Plug-in API.  You have to include the function listed on that page to use the function.

To make use of one of the plug-in API functions below, you simply need to include it in the Javascript available for your page, after you load the DataTables library, but before you initialise the DataTable. After that, you will be able to initialise the table, and call the function on the resulting object.

Comment: I can use the datatable and fnfilter just fine but not the fnfilterclear what file do i need to include for that to work?

Comment: http://datatables.net/plug-ins/api#fnFilterClear.  You need to include the actual js code, not an include file for things on the plug-in page.

Comment: I added the $.fn.dataTableExt all that code before my $(document).ready and I am still getting the same issue, I guess im not understanding what code to include.

Comment: It has to be after the datatables.js include and before you try to use it.